# Connect mysql client to a mysql server by using custom port

Tags: mysql

My problem is related to mysql client. When i want to connect on a mysql server that is exposed from docker with a port 3307, the mysql client always connect to the mysql started on host machine on port 3306.

The command that I used to connect:

```bash
mysql -h localhost -P 3307 -u root -p
```

The source of problem is the option *-P*. It seems that this option is not recognized in the command. Because, it always works even if I put wrong port:

```bash
mysql -u root -P 1111 -p #It works
```

**So, why -P option does not work? How to specify the port of mysql server into mysql client shell?**

Comment: How do you know it is connected to port 3306 and not 3307?

Comment: @SalmanA MySQL version is not the same. I used MySQL 8 in host machine and MySQL 5.7 in the docker container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the problem is `-h localhost`. That hostname is treated special by MySQL, it means the client connects via the UNIX socket, not TCP. So the port is ignored.

You can verify with the `status` command:

```
mysql> status
...
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket:    /tmp/mysql.sock
```

To force use of TCP, use the hostname `127.0.0.1`. Then try the `status` command again.

```
mysql> status
...
Connection:     127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
TCP port:       3306
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks!